# ImageView crop and scale image to smaller size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to get my images to appear in my image view so that if an image is say 600x400 and my image view is 200x200 that the image is scaled to 300x200 and then the extra width is cropped out so that the image appears as a 200x200 image.  I have played with the various ScaleTypes but i can't find one that suits what i want. I want something like a combo of ScaleType.FIT_XY and ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to scale down the image using the inSampleSize as shown here: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

and then use ScaleType.CENTER_CROP to show the image in the view.